# Laravel erro conexão com banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel

Uso mamp e configurei o arquivo database.php assim

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost:8889'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'estoque_laravel'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'teste'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '123'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Porem no quando testo me retorna :

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
```

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ProdutoController extends Controller { // cria controller para ser exibido
    public function lista(){
        $html = '<h1>Listagem de produtos com Laravel</h1>';
        $html .= '<ul>';
        $produtos = DB::select('select * from produtos');
        foreach ($produtos as $p) {
            $html .= '<li> Nome: ’. $p->nome .';
        }
        Descrição: '. $p->descricao .’</li>';

        $html .= '</ul>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Arquivo Routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function() { // func exec ao acessar o public - no caso retonamos um txt na func padrao retorna uma view
    return '<h1>Primeira lógica com Laravel</h1>';
});

Route::get('/outra', function() // ao passar o parametro outra ele envia outra msg
{
    return '<h1>Outra lógica com Laravel</h1>';
});

Route::get('/produtos', 'ProdutoController@lista'); // cria rout para o produtocontroller
```

Como poderia resolver ?
Obrigado

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31695/discussion-on-question-by-augusto-furlan-laravel-erro-conexao-com-banco-de-dados)

Answer (score 6):

Tive o mesmo problema e resolvi usando os comandos a seguir:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer de duas formas:

A **primeira** é editar o arquivo `.env` que vem na pasta raiz do projeto quando você cria o projeto em Laravel.

No arquivo `.env` encontrará algo assim:

```
DB_HOST= HOST
DB_DATABASE= DATABASE NAME
DB_USERNAME= USERNAME 
DB_PASSWORD= PASSWORD
```

É só colocar os dados referente ao seu banco de dados.

Daí no arquivo `database.php`, você deixa assim:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

A função `env()` irá buscar os dados que você preencheu no arquivo `.env.

Uma **segunda** forma é apagar a função `env()` do arquivo `database.php` e colocar direto no valor da variável.

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database_name',
    'username'  => 'username',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Vai funcionar assim também.

Usar o arquivo `.env` torna a sua aplicação mais segura, visto ser um arquivo oculto dentro da hospedagem, assim como o `.htaccess`. Aí ninguém poderia ver o arquivo que mostra os dados para entrar na sua base.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, você conseguiu ter sucesso?

Comment: Sim @PedroSoares. Qual seu problema ?

Comment: Entra nessa URL, é o meu problema http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168218/35723

Comment: Se puder me ajudar cara, vai ajudar muito, muito mesmo